# The FormData not work with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, form-data

I try to make this form "POST" in AJAX but I do not load the user, when I get on the server does not get anything, any suggestions?

This is the form

```
<form method="POST" action="/ajaxpost">
   <input type="text" name="user"/>
   <input type="submit" value="SEND"/>
</form>



//here trying to do the same form but ajax, I have this button that calls the function "sendAjax ()"

<input type="submit" value="SEND"/>


//The function this does not work. fail data to the server

 function sendAjax(){
         // HTML5 form data object.
        var fd = new FormData();

        fd.append("user", 'JOAN FREDO USERNAME');

        $.ajax({
            url: '/ajaxpost',
            data: fd,
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is content type, try to set the contentType to false, so that jQuery will set it

```
function sendAjax() {
    // HTML5 form data object.
    var fd = new FormData();

    fd.append("user", 'JOAN FREDO USERNAME');
    fd.append("user2", 'asd');

    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajaxpost',
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zc9ef8hg/) - <sub>you can see the data sent using network tab of browser developer tools</sub>

Answer (score 0):

first add an **id** and a **name** to the submit button

then,

```
$('body').on('click','#submit',function(){  

       // var user        = 'JOAN FREDO USERNAME';

        var form_data   =   new FormData();   

        form_data.append("user", 'JOAN FREDO USERNAME');
        //form_data.append('user',user);



        $.ajax({
                url         :   'someURL.php',  //mention valid url
                dataType    :   'text',
                cache       :   false,
                contentType :   false,
                processData :   false,
                data        :   form_data,                
                type        :   'post',
                success     :   function(data){
                             alert(data);                   

            }
        });
});
```

works fine for me...
comment for any questions...